# How can I transform this data using underscore js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, underscore.js

I have some data that is being returned to me from a REST API. I'd like it in a certain format for my Angular 2 app.

How can I perform the following data transformation using underscore js?

Data as returned from REST API:

```
[    
    {
        "ProductVariantID": "133",
        "ProductID": "259",
        "ProductGender": "Male",
        "Size": "17.5",
        "Color": "Red",
        "MSRP": "0",
        "MAP": "0",
        "UPC": "99999106"
    },
    {
        "ProductVariantID": "128",
        "ProductID": "259",
        "ProductGender": "Male",
        "Size": "17.5",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "MSRP": "0",
        "MAP": "0",
        "UPC": "99999101"
    },
    {
        "ProductVariantID": "130",
        "ProductID": "259",
        "ProductGender": "Male",
        "Size": "19.5",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "MSRP": "0",
        "MAP": "0",
        "UPC": "99999103"
    },
    {
        "ProductVariantID": "129",
        "ProductID": "259",
        "ProductGender": "Male",
        "Size": "18.5",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "MSRP": "0",
        "MAP": "0",
        "UPC": "99999102"
    },
    {
        "ProductVariantID": "132",
        "ProductID": "259",
        "ProductGender": "Male",
        "Size": "15.5",
        "Color": "Red",
        "MSRP": "0",
        "MAP": "0",
        "UPC": "99999105"
    },    
    {
        "ProductVariantID": "131",
        "ProductID": "259",
        "ProductGender": "Male",
        "Size": "21.5",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "MSRP": "0",
        "MAP": "0",
        "UPC": "99999104"
    },
    {
        "ProductVariantID": "127",
        "ProductID": "259",
        "ProductGender": "Male",
        "Size": "15.5",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "MSRP": "0",
        "MAP": "0",
        "UPC": "99999100"
    }       
]
```

I want to transform it into the following. Note that the top level array is sorted in alphabetical order on the "Color" property of its objects and the Variants arrays are sorted by the "Size" property numerically of its objects. Essentially, I want a new array of objects, grouped by color and containing the original objects in a "Variants" array property.

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "Color": "Blue",
        "Variants": [
             {
                "ProductVariantID": "127",
                "ProductID": "259",
                "ProductGender": "Male",
                "Size": "15.5",
                "Color": "Blue",
                "MSRP": "0",
                "MAP": "0",
                "UPC": "99999100"
            },
            {
                "ProductVariantID": "128",
                "ProductID": "259",
                "ProductGender": "Male",
                "Size": "17.5",
                "Color": "Blue",
                "MSRP": "0",
                "MAP": "0",
                "UPC": "99999101"
            },
            {
                "ProductVariantID": "129",
                "ProductID": "259",
                "ProductGender": "Male",
                "Size": "18.5",
                "Color": "Blue",
                "MSRP": "0",
                "MAP": "0",
                "UPC": "99999102"
            },
            {
                "ProductVariantID": "130",
                "ProductID": "259",
                "ProductGender": "Male",
                "Size": "19.5",
                "Color": "Blue",
                "MSRP": "0",
                "MAP": "0",
                "UPC": "99999103"
            },
            {
                "ProductVariantID": "131",
                "ProductID": "259",
                "ProductGender": "Male",
                "Size": "21.5",
                "Color": "Blue",
                "MSRP": "0",
                "MAP": "0",
                "UPC": "99999104"
            }      
        ],            
    }
    {
        "Color": "Red",
        "Variants": [
             {
                "ProductVariantID": "132",
                "ProductID": "259",
                "ProductGender": "Male",
                "Size": "15.5",
                "Color": "Red",
                "MSRP": "0",
                "MAP": "0",
                "UPC": "99999101"
            },  
            {
                "ProductVariantID": "133",
                "ProductID": "259",
                "ProductGender": "Male",
                "Size": "17.5",
                "Color": "Red",
                "MSRP": "0",
                "MAP": "0",
                "UPC": "99999101"
            },      
        ],            
    }
]
```

Comment: You'll need to show us what you've tried before we help.

Comment: Why do you need to use underscore? Should be able to do it simply with a for loop and multidimensional arrays

Comment: I don't have to use underscore but it seems like underscore would allow an elegant way to do this...

I've tried the groupBy() function but it gives me the data in this form:

{
  "Blue": [
    {
      "ProductVariantID": "127",
      "ProductID": "259",
      "ProductGender": "Male",
      "Size": "15.5",
      "Color": "Blue",
      "MSRP": "0",
      "MAP": "0",
      "UPC": "99999100"
    },
     ...
    ],
   "Red": [
       ....
    ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map after group by to create required output

```
var temp1=_.groupBy(result, 'Color');
_.map(temp1,function(item,key){return {'Color':key,'Variants':item}});
```